# sweetModal.js bug if height is too big

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [SweetModal.js](https://github.com/adeptoas/sweet-modal) and if the height of the modal is more that the screen height there is no way to scroll to the top of the modal. You can check it on the business owner registration form ( at the right side ) http://om.hello21group.ru/ just add a few places to increase the height of the modal

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

```
.sweet-modal-overlay {
    overflow: scroll !important;
}

.sweet-modal-box{
    max-height: unset !important;
    height: unset !important;
}
```

It allows you to scroll text on the sweetModal.

Answer (score 1):

In your css, you have given

```
.sweet-modal{
  top:50%;  /* . -- issue -- */
}
```

It is causing the issue. Pls change its value to some other value such as
`top:80%;` may solve your problem